# Subclassing NSView Subclasses (NSTextField, NSButton, NSPopUpButton)

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, appkit

I've been wrestling with applying my custom styles ([example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/320chi85n7ec5oj/Screenshot%202016-06-08%2017.04.29.png?dl=0)) to the OSX desktop app I've been building, and I'm wondering what the paradigms/idioms are for doing this.

- I'm using X/Nibs for laying out the components on the windows
- I'm setting the components' class to a custom subclass of the out-of-the-box component (`NSTextField`, `NSButton`, and `NSPopUpButton` for example)
- I'm overriding `viewWillDraw` in some, `init?` in others and making them all `wantsLayer` and setting attributes on those layers

This seems *extremely* clumsy at best, and some visual things are impossible to handle this way, like adding padding to an `NSTextField`.  <strike>Am I supposed to create a `NSTextFieldCell` subclass and instantiate one and set it to the cell?  Doing that breaks the text field altogether. I'm seeing [other places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926275/what-class-to-subclass-nsview-or-nsbutton) that you should subclass `NSButtonCell`, but I can't assign that as the class of a button in the X/Nib.</strike> (@Willeke informed me in the comments that it's possible to select a control's cell, and therefore assign a custom cell class by clicking on the control again)

A lot of people are describing how to do certain changes to visual components in `viewDidLoad` with a reference to a component, which seems very tedious if you have button/textfield styles that apply to all in the project.  It seems like every visual change I've made with subclassing has been a nightmare, and there's no pattern for what visual changes are made where for different components.  Subclassing seems like the best option for any size of project if you want to make your code reusable, but am I missing something?  Is there some other pattern or idiom that I'm missing?

Comment: Do you have any examples of your *custom styles*?. If we can see what effects you're trying to replicate it might be easier to provide assistance

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/320chi85n7ec5oj/Screenshot%202016-06-08%2017.04.29.png?dl=0 shows an example of an `NSTextField` and `NSButton` that we would want, and we would want the `NSPopUpButton` to have the same styles as the text fields.

Comment: You can change the class of a cell in the XIB in the same way you change the class of the control. Select the cell by clicking again (don't double click) or use the path control at the top or use the Document Outline on the left.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that.  Is there a pattern regarding visual styles generally being associated with the cell of controls, or no pattern really?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did end up subclassing `NSTextFieldCell`, and from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9027461/895453) I derived the following for the specific problem I was facing:

```
class TGTextFieldCell: NSTextFieldCell {
    override init(imageCell image: NSImage?) {
        super.init(imageCell: image)
    }

    override init(textCell aString: String) {
        super.init(textCell: aString)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func drawingRectForBounds(theRect: NSRect) -> NSRect {
        let rectInset = NSMakeRect(theRect.origin.x + 7, theRect.origin.y + 7, theRect.size.width, theRect.size.height)
        return super.drawingRectForBounds(rectInset)
    }
}
```

It still seems that customizing views is much more complicated than it needs to be (moving on to [customizing focus styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37870474/osx-nstextfield-with-layer-background-color-not-working), for example), but that's a question to I have yet to hear a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

subclassing an NSTextFieldCell is the best option, but its a long battle for sure.
Like Willeke sez, change the class of a cell in the XIB.

I used BGHUDAppKit as a starting point, and made major mods / upgrades over the years.

FWIW here's my current version of BGHUDTextFieldCell.mm, which uses a bunch of my own category methods like attrStringWithColor, but the general idea should be clear.

Dealing with focus ring animations is particularly troublesome.
The only way to draw your custom focus ring is to subclass a LOT of stuff, including NSTextField and possibly its superview, so that you can hijack the default NSTextView focus ring.
However, I highly recommend NOT subclassing NSTextView itself... see setupFieldEditorColors below.

```
  //  BGHUDTextFieldCell.m
  //  BGHUDAppKit
  //
  //  Created by BinaryGod on 6/2/08.
  //
  //  Copyright (c) 2008, Tim Davis (BinaryMethod.com, binary.god@gmail.com)
  //  All rights reserved.
  //
  //  Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without modification,
  //  are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
  //
  //        Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice, this
  //    list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
  //
  //        Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice,
  //    this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation and/or
  //    other materials provided with the distribution.
  //
  //        Neither the name of the BinaryMethod.com nor the names of its contributors
  //    may be used to endorse or promote products derived from this software without
  //    specific prior written permission.
  //
  //    THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS AS IS AND
  //    ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED
  //    WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED.
  //    IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT,
  //    INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING,
  //    BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA,
  //    OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY,
  //    WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE)
  //    ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE 
  //    POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.

  #import "BGHUDTextFieldCell.h"
  #import "VNSColorCategory.h"
  #import "BGThemeMbox.h"
  @interface BGHUDTextFieldCell (Private)
  - (void)doInit;
  - (NSRect)_focusRingFrameForFrame:(NSRect)aRect cellFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame; // bug fix
  @end
  @implementation BGHUDTextFieldCell

  @synthesize themeKey;
  @synthesize LayerKey;
  @synthesize defaultTextColor;
  @synthesize isVerticallyCentered;
  @synthesize fillsBackground;
  //@synthesize LayerKey;
  #pragma mark Drawing Functions

  - (id)initTextCell:(NSString *)aString {

     self = [super initTextCell: aString];

     if(self) {
        self.themeKey = @"gradientTheme";
        [self doInit];

     }

     return self;
  }

  - (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *) aDecoder {

     self = [super initWithCoder: aDecoder];

     if(self) {

        if([aDecoder containsValueForKey: @"themeKey"]) {

           self.themeKey = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey: @"themeKey"];
        } else {

           self.themeKey = @"gradientTheme";
        }

        [self doInit];

     }

     return self;
  }

  - (void)doInit
  {
     self.defaultTextColor = [[[BGThemeManager keyedManager] themeForKey: self.themeKey] textColor];
     [self setTextColor:self.defaultTextColor];

     if([self drawsBackground]) {
        fillsBackground = YES;
        ////NSLog( @"t%d BGHUDTextFieldCell initTextCell ignoring nib backgroundColor %@, use fillsBackground", [self tag], [self backgroundColor] );
     }
     else // kpk 2010... always draw background?
     {
        fillsBackground = NO;
     }

     [self setDrawsBackground: NO];
  }


  -(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder {

     [super encodeWithCoder: aCoder];

     [aCoder encodeObject: self.themeKey forKey: @"themeKey"];
  }

  - ( NSRect ) adjustFrameToVerticallyCenterText: ( NSRect ) frame
  {
     // super would normally draw text at the top of the cell
     int offset = floor ( ( NSHeight ( frame ) - ( [ [ self font ] ascender] - [ [ self font ] descender ] ) ) / 2 );
     frame = NSInsetRect ( frame, 0.0, offset );
     return frame;
  }

  - (NSText *)setUpFieldEditorAttributes:(NSText *)textObj
  {
     BGTheme *theTheme = [[BGThemeManager keyedManager] themeForKey: self.themeKey];
     //textObj = [super setUpFieldEditorAttributes:textObj];
     NSTextView *theTextView = (NSTextView *)textObj;   
     if ( [theTextView isKindOfClass:[NSTextView class]] )
     {
        //NSLog( @"t%d text view editor %@ bgcolor %@ insert color %@", [self tag], [theTextView description], [theTextView backgroundColor], [theTextView insertionPointColor] ); 
        [BGTheme setupFieldEditorColors:theTheme editor:theTextView window:[[self controlView] window]  forObject:self];
     }

     return textObj;
  }

  -(void)drawWithFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView *)controlView {
     waitIfNeeded(self);
     if ( isVerticallyCentered ) // kpk 2013 _cFlags.vCentered = 1;
        cellFrame = [ self adjustFrameToVerticallyCenterText: cellFrame ];

     // kpk 2009/2010: get the fieldEditorView (NSTextView) to display properly as well.
     // Also be careful not to cause continuous redraws by setting text color unnecessarily.   
     NSWindow *theWindow = [controlView window];

     NSTextView* fieldEditorView = (NSTextView*)[theWindow fieldEditor: NO forObject: self]; 
     id fieldEditorDelegate = [fieldEditorView delegate];   
     if ( [theWindow firstResponder] == fieldEditorView && fieldEditorDelegate == controlView )
     {    
        //NSLog( @"t%d fieldEditorView bg color %@ self %@ controlView %@", [self tag], [self backgroundColor], [self description], [controlView description] );
        BGTheme *theTheme = [[BGThemeManager keyedManager] themeForKey: self.themeKey];
        if ( fieldEditorView )
           [BGTheme setupFieldEditorColors:theTheme editor:fieldEditorView window:theWindow forObject:self];

        NSRect editFrame = [fieldEditorView frame];
        NSRect controlViewFrame = [controlView frame];
        if ( [controlView isKindOfClass:[NSTextField class]] && NSIntersectsRect(controlViewFrame, editFrame ))
        {
           return;
        }
     }
     fieldEditorView = nil; // kpk 2010: we are done with this now

     //Create Path
     NSBezierPath *path = [[NSBezierPath new] autorelease];

     if([self bezelStyle] == NSTextFieldRoundedBezel) {

        [path appendBezierPathWithArcWithCenter: NSMakePoint(cellFrame.origin.x + (cellFrame.size.height /2), cellFrame.origin.y + (cellFrame.size.height /2))
                                 radius: cellFrame.size.height /2
                              startAngle: 90
                                endAngle: 270];

        [path appendBezierPathWithArcWithCenter: NSMakePoint(cellFrame.origin.x + (cellFrame.size.width - (cellFrame.size.height /2)), cellFrame.origin.y + (cellFrame.size.height /2))
                                 radius: cellFrame.size.height /2
                              startAngle: 270
                                endAngle: 90];

        [path closePath];
     } else {

        // kpk 2010: not desireable for table view cells
        //[path appendBezierPathWithRoundedRect: cellFrame xRadius: 3.0f yRadius: 3.0f];
        //[path appendBezierPathWithRect:cellFrame];
     }

     //Draw Background
     if(fillsBackground) {
        [[[[BGThemeManager keyedManager] themeForKey: self.themeKey] textFillColor] set];
        // kpk 2010: not desireable for table view cells
        NSRectFill( cellFrame );
        //[path fill];
     }
     else if ( [self isEditable] )
     {
        [[[[BGThemeManager keyedManager] themeForKey: self.themeKey] textFillColor] set]; 
        [path fill];      
        // NSRectFill( cellFrame );
     }

     if([self isBezeled] || [self isBordered]) {

        [NSGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState];

        if([super showsFirstResponder] && [theWindow isKeyWindow] && 
           ([self focusRingType] == NSFocusRingTypeDefault ||
           [self focusRingType] == NSFocusRingTypeExterior)) {

           [[[[BGThemeManager keyedManager] themeForKey: self.themeKey] focusRing] set];
        }

        //Check State
        if([self isEnabled]) {

           [[[[BGThemeManager keyedManager] themeForKey: self.themeKey] darkStrokeColor] set];
        } else {

           [[[[BGThemeManager keyedManager] themeForKey: self.themeKey] disabledStrokeColor] set];
        }

        [path setLineWidth: 1.0f];
        [path stroke];

        [NSGraphicsContext restoreGraphicsState];
     }

     // Check to see if the attributed placeholder has been set or not
     //if(![self placeholderAttributedString]) {
     if(![self placeholderAttributedString] && [self placeholderString]) {

        //Nope lets create it
        NSDictionary *attribs = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: 
                           [[[BGThemeManager keyedManager] themeForKey: self.themeKey] placeholderTextColor] , NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil];

        //Set it
        [self setPlaceholderAttributedString: [[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString: [self placeholderString] attributes: [attribs autorelease]] autorelease]];
     }

     //Adjust Frame so Text Draws correctly
     switch ([self controlSize]) {

        case NSRegularControlSize:

           if([self bezelStyle] == NSTextFieldRoundedBezel) { // kpk 2010

              cellFrame.origin.y += 1;
           }
           break;

        case NSSmallControlSize:

           if([self bezelStyle] == NSTextFieldRoundedBezel) {

              cellFrame.origin.y += 1;
           }
           break;

        case NSMiniControlSize:

           if([self bezelStyle] == NSTextFieldRoundedBezel) {

              cellFrame.origin.x += 1;
           }
           break;

        default:
           break;
     }

     [self drawInteriorWithFrame: cellFrame inView: controlView];
  }

  -(void)drawInteriorWithFrame:(NSRect) cellFrame inView:(NSView *) controlView {     
     if ( [controlView conformsToProtocol:@protocol(EditingAlignmentProtocol)] )
     {

        if ( [controlView isKindOfClass:[NSControl class]] && [(NSControl *)controlView currentEditor] )
        {       
           // DLog( @"danger: skipping draw to avoid call to validateEditing!" );
           return;
        }

        cellFrame = [(id <EditingAlignmentProtocol>)controlView editingAlignmentRect];
        cellFrame = [self titleRectForBounds:cellFrame];
        NSAttributedString *str = [self attributedStringValue];
        [str drawInRect:cellFrame];  
        return;
     }

     [super drawInteriorWithFrame: cellFrame inView: controlView];
  }

  - (NSColor *)highlightColorWithFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView *)controlView;
  {

     // Corbin Dunn (the apple author) says to return nil here
  //   The proper thing to do:
  //      
  //      1. Subclass NSCell, NSTextFieldCell, or whatever other cell you want.
  //      2. Override:
  //      
  //      - (NSColor *)highlightColorWithFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView
  //                                                                     *)controlView
  //      
  //      and return nil.
  //      
  //      That is the correct thing to do for Tiger, Leopard, etc.
  //         
  //         corbin
     if ( [controlView isKindOfClass: [NSTableView class]] )
        return nil; // [[BGThemeMbox instance] cellHighlightColor];
     return [super highlightColorWithFrame:cellFrame inView:controlView];
  }

  // warning mIsEditingOrSelecting is probably not used correctly when call stack is deep,
  // while switching from one edit field to another
  - (NSRect)drawingRectForBounds:(NSRect)aRect
  {
     id controlView = [self controlView];
     NSRect newRect;
     if ( [controlView conformsToProtocol:@protocol(EditingAlignmentProtocol)] )
        newRect = [(id <EditingAlignmentProtocol>)controlView editingAlignmentRect];
     else
     {
        newRect = [super drawingRectForBounds:aRect];
        if (mIsEditingOrSelecting == NO)
        {
           // Get our ideal size for current text
           NSSize textSize = [self cellSizeForBounds:aRect];
           if ( textSize.height >= 22 && textSize.height > newRect.size.height )
           {
              newRect.origin.y = -(textSize.height - newRect.size.height) + 6;
              newRect.size.height = textSize.height + (textSize.height - newRect.size.height);
           }      
        }
     }

     return newRect;
  }

  // hack alert: undocumented _focusRingFrameForFrame
  // this fixes a hard to reproduce bug where NSTextView fieldEditor *sometimes* 
  // leaves behind white clutter.
  // to reproduce, have 10, 11, or 12 items in scene table, then edit xFade type.
  // scene table will have white clutter.
  - (NSRect)_focusRingFrameForFrame:(NSRect)aRect cellFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame
  {
     id ctl = [self controlView];
     if ( [ctl conformsToProtocol:@protocol(EditingAlignmentProtocol)] )
        return [ctl bounds];
     else
        return cellFrame;
  }

  //    This method is adapted from Red Sweater Software's RSVerticallyCenteredTextField class.
  //  Created by Daniel Jalkut on 6/17/06.
  //  Copyright 2006 Red Sweater Software. All rights reserved.
  //    MIT License
  - (void)selectWithFrame:(NSRect)aRect inView:(NSView *)controlView editor:(NSText *)textObj delegate:(id)anObject start:(NSInteger)selStart length:(NSInteger)selLength
  {
     if ( isVerticallyCentered ) // kpk 2013 _cFlags.vCentered replacement
        aRect = [ self adjustFrameToVerticallyCenterText: aRect ];
     aRect = [self drawingRectForBounds:aRect];
     mIsEditingOrSelecting = YES;
     [super selectWithFrame:aRect inView:controlView editor:textObj delegate:anObject start:selStart length:selLength];
     mIsEditingOrSelecting = NO;
     //NSLog( @"selectWithFrame %@ %@", controlView, textObj );
  }

  //    This method is adapted from Red Sweater Software's RSVerticallyCenteredTextField class.
  //  Created by Daniel Jalkut on 6/17/06.
  //  Copyright 2006 Red Sweater Software. All rights reserved.
  //    MIT License
  - (void)editWithFrame:(NSRect)aRect inView:(NSView *)controlView editor:(NSText *)textObj delegate:(id)anObject event:(NSEvent *)theEvent
  {   
     if ( isVerticallyCentered ) // kpk 2013 _cFlags.vCentered replacement
        aRect = [ self adjustFrameToVerticallyCenterText: aRect ];
     //NSLog( @"editWithFrame %@", controlView );
     aRect = [self drawingRectForBounds:aRect];
     mIsEditingOrSelecting = YES;   
     [super editWithFrame:[self drawingRectForBounds:aRect] inView:controlView editor:textObj delegate:anObject event:theEvent];
     mIsEditingOrSelecting = NO;   
  }

  -(void)_drawKeyboardFocusRingWithFrame:(NSRect)fp8 inView:(id)fp24 {
     //NSLog( @"_drawKeyboardFocusRingWithFrame" );
  }

  - (void)drawWithExpansionFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView *)view
  {
     [[[[BGThemeManager keyedManager] themeForKey: @"gradientTheme"] darkStrokeColor] set];
     NSRectFill(cellFrame);
     [self drawInteriorWithFrame:cellFrame inView:view];
  }

  - (void) setAttributedColor: (NSColor *)iColor
  {
     NSMutableAttributedString *attrStr = [[self stringValue] attrStringWithColor: iColor];
     [attrStr setAlignment: [self alignment] range:[attrStr fullRange]];
     [attrStr setFont:[self font]];
     [self setAttributedStringValue:attrStr];
     if ( iColor )
        [self setTextColor:iColor];
     else if ( [self isEditable] )
        [self setTextColor: [NSColor defaultTextColor]];
     else
        [self setTextColor:[NSColor dimTextColor]];
  }

  #pragma mark -
  #pragma mark Helper Methods

  -(void)dealloc {

     [super dealloc];
  }

  #pragma mark -

  @end
```

The .h file:

```
      #import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
  #import "BGThemeManager.h"

  @protocol EditingAlignmentProtocol
  - (NSRect)editingAlignmentRect; // used to align NSTextView field editor frame
  - (void)setIsSettingUpFieldEditor:(bool)flag;
  - (bool)isSettingUpFieldEditor;
  @end

  @interface BGHUDTextFieldCell : NSTextFieldCell {

     BOOL fillsBackground;
     NSString *themeKey;
     NSString *LayerKey;
     NSColor *defaultTextColor;
     BOOL mIsEditingOrSelecting;
     BOOL isVerticallyCentered;
  }

  @property (retain) NSString *themeKey;
  @property (retain) NSString *LayerKey;
  @property (retain) NSColor *defaultTextColor;
  @property (assign) BOOL isVerticallyCentered;
  @property (assign) BOOL fillsBackground;
  - (void)doInit; // if overriden, must call [super doInit];
  - (void) setAttributedColor: (NSColor *)iColor;
  @end
```

setupFieldEditor

```
+(void)setupFieldEditorColors:(BGTheme *)iTheme editor:(NSTextView *)iFieldEditorView window:(NSWindow *)iWindow forObject:(id)anObject
{
   if ( iFieldEditorView == nil )
      return;

   if ( !iFieldEditorView || ![iFieldEditorView isKindOfClass:[NSTextView class]] )
      return;

   // setup attributes such that editing in the field editor will
   // occur at the exact same position as the title cell was drawn
   [[iFieldEditorView textContainer] setLineFragmentPadding:2.0];
   //[[iFieldEditorView layoutManager] setTypesetterBehavior:NSTypesetterBehavior_10_2_WithCompatibility];
   NSRange theSelRange = [iFieldEditorView selectedRange];   
   @try
   {   
      if ( [anObject respondsToSelector: @selector(themeKey)] || 
          ( [anObject respondsToSelector: @selector(cell)] && 
           [[anObject cell] respondsToSelector: @selector(themeKey)] ))
      {
         //NSLog( @"theSelRange %@", NSStringFromRange(theSelRange));
         NSColor *theTextColor = [iTheme textColor];
         if ( [iFieldEditorView insertionPointColor] != theTextColor )
            [iFieldEditorView setInsertionPointColor:theTextColor]; 
         //if ( [iFieldEditorView textColor] != theTextColor )
         //{
            //NSLog( @"cell editor tc %@\n   change to %@", [iFieldEditorView textColor], theTextColor );
         //   [iFieldEditorView setTextColor: theTextColor];
         //}

         //NSLog( @"cell editor createFlag %d", createFlag);
         //if ( ![iFieldEditorView isKindOfClass:[BGHUDTextView class]] )
         //  iFieldEditorView = [BGHUDTextView alloc] init
         NSColor *theBgColor = [iTheme cellEditingFillColor];
         if ( [iFieldEditorView backgroundColor] != theBgColor )
         {
            //NSLog( @"cell editor bg %@\n   change to %@", [iFieldEditorView backgroundColor], theBgColor );
            [iFieldEditorView setBackgroundColor:theBgColor];
         }

         if ( [iFieldEditorView drawsBackground] == NO )
            [iFieldEditorView setDrawsBackground:YES];



         NSMutableDictionary *theDict = [[[iFieldEditorView selectedTextAttributes] mutableCopy] autorelease];        
         //NSColor *theSelTextColor = nil;
         if([iWindow isKeyWindow])
         {
            if ( [theDict objectForKey: NSBackgroundColorAttributeName] != [iTheme selectionHighlightActiveColor] )
            {  
               [theDict setObject: [iTheme selectionHighlightActiveColor]
                        forKey: NSBackgroundColorAttributeName];
               //theSelTextColor = [iTheme selectionTextActiveColor];
               //kpk why doesn't this work?
               [theDict setObject: [iTheme selectionTextActiveColor]
                        forKey: NSForegroundColorAttributeName];
               [iFieldEditorView setSelectedTextAttributes:theDict]; 
            }
         }
         else
         {
            if ( [theDict objectForKey: NSBackgroundColorAttributeName] != [iTheme selectionHighlightInActiveColor] )
            {  
               [theDict setObject: [iTheme selectionHighlightInActiveColor]
                           forKey: NSBackgroundColorAttributeName];
               //theSelTextColor = [iTheme selectionTextInActiveColor];         
               //kpk why doesn't this work?
               [theDict setObject: [iTheme selectionTextInActiveColor]
                           forKey: NSForegroundColorAttributeName]; 
               [iFieldEditorView setSelectedTextAttributes:theDict];                
            }
         }

/*
         NSString *theStr = [iFieldEditorView string];
         if ( !theStr )
            return;


         NSUInteger theStrLength = [theStr length];
         if ( theStrLength > 0 )
            [iFieldEditorView setTextColor: theTextColor
                                     range: NSMakeRange(0, theStrLength)];

         if(theSelRange.length > 0 && theSelRange.length <= theStrLength || theSelRange.location <= theStrLength && NSMaxRange(theSelRange) <= theStrLength )
         { 
            [iFieldEditorView setTextColor: theSelTextColor
                                     range: [iFieldEditorView selectedRange]];
         }
         else
         {

         }
         */


      }   
   }
   @catch(...)
   {
      //VLog::Log( kLogErrorType | kLogNoFlood, @"caught exception in setupFieldEditorColors %@", NSStringFromRange(theSelRange));
      NSLog( @"caught exception in setupFieldEditorColors %@", NSStringFromRange(theSelRange) );
   }      
}
```